# Read gmail from Laravel

Tags: laravel, gmail-api

I have a requirement to read given Gmail id's messages in Laravel.

I found https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail which already have the implementation. But I stuck with getting the token for particular Gmail account. Note that I already created a project in console and I have the `credential.json` and updated in `.env`

I just want to get the flow clear and get to know how can I create access and refresh tokens forever(because I'm going to read only one Gmail account).

Also I there is any other options to read the mail, help me to try that out(note that I have the gmail mail id which I have to read).

Comment: You could utilise the Gmail API. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

Comment: @OMiShah we have to read the email, whenever an api is called with message ID. Since this is going to happen in the server level(no ui), how can we get it done for particular gmail id. (my doubt is whether we can get tokens manually? if yes, how can we do that?)

Comment: When you say "create access and refresh tokens forever" do you mean code that works forever or tokens that are valid forever?

Comment: Go though the documentation first

Comment: So essentially you just want to refresh the access token?

Comment: If I were you I will go with php imap functions to read emails, you can also use it with laravel's command's (cron job) to read it every x minute or so.